# How to make a dynamic api url in angularjs for a dreamfactory stored procedure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

If im useing a factory/service to call my api in dreamfactory.

```
FoundationApp.factory('testAPI', function($resource, ChildID) {
    return $resource('http://Domain.com/rest/RemoteDB/_proc/TimeLog_Checkin(:ChildID)/?app_name=App&fields=*', {ChildID: @ChildID}, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
})
```

how would i change the ChildID useing a control with a get function to make a call to the api with a certain ChildID that is entered by the user?

```
.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope','$resource','$routeParams','testAPI', function($scope,$resource,$routeParams,testAPI) {
    console.log("Welcome to Test");
    $scope.TestFunction = function() {
        test.get($scope.ChildID);
    };
}])
```

The child id is obtained by the html document. here is the code for that.

```
<div class="well">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="TestFunction()">Get all Clients</button>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ChildID">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I have done some testing myself and i made the call by replaceing ChildID in the url with the ChildID im looking for

```
http://Domain.com/rest/RemoteDB/_proc/TimeLog_Checkin(1)/?app_name=App&fields=*
```

and it worked but i need a dynamic url to work with the user input.

I tried to look up ways to impliment this idea but every exsample didn't fit my case well enough to solve my problem.

please any help would be amazing. I'v spent quite a few hour working on this.

Comment: ok couple of things, i don't think resource is the right tool for this job that does not seem to be a rest api which is the intent of the resource  factory. if you are only going to do a get you are better off using simple $http is more memory efficient. Resource will create a constructor which will have several methods matching HTTP methods and much more that you will not be needing. it will be simpler for you just to create a function in your factory that takes the child id and conforms an the url to make the AJAX call

Comment: @Dayan Moreno Leon Thank you for your input, you are talking about this process right? [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), most of the exsamples i saw was useing [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$resource). I'll give it a try and let you all know if it worked.

Comment: Sounds good. like a said, $resource is a powerfull tool but it can be too much or not flexible enough for what you want in this case your is actually pretty simple you just need to do  `testApi.update({childId:"childId", ....})`, or 
`var api = new testApi({childId:"id"});  api.otherProp="value"; api.$update();` but is still not the right tool for the job

Comment: @Dayan Moreno Leon You are a beautiful person. if you want to make the answer ill mark it and vote it.

Comment: Gee thx for the compliment glad to help i made my comment an answer. thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$resource is a powerful tool, but it can be too much or not flexible enough for what you want. But in this case is actually pretty simple. You just need to do

`testApi.update({childId:"childId", ....})`

or

```
var api = new testApi({childId:"id"}); 
api.otherProp="value"; 
api.$update();
```

Comment: for those of you who are wondering how i applied this to my code. i ended up getting rid of the factory/service modual and changed my factory service call to a simple     
    $http.get('http://Domain.com/rest/RemoteDB/_proc/TimeLog_Checkin('+$scope.ChildID+')/?app_name=App&fields=*) 

in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate  `ChildId` with url like this

```
FoundationApp.factory('testAPI', function($resource, ChildID) {
     return $resource('http://Domain.com/rest/RemoteDB/_proc/TimeLog_Checkin(' + ChildID + ')/?app_name=App&fields=*', {ChildID: ChildID}, {
         update: {
             method: 'PUT'
         }
     });
})
```

I don't know what's meant by @ sign, so I removed that

Comment: ljaz Yeah that is what i figured too but i couldn't get the factory to access $scope to get that data to concatenate.

Comment: then you should define a function inside factory

Answer (score 0):

Oh I missed that you are not using any function to get parameters, do something like this.
You will call something like `data = testAPI.getData($scope.ChildID)`

```
FoundationApp.factory('testAPI', function($resource) {
 return { 
          getData: function(ChildID) {
                    return $resource('http://Domain.com/rest/RemoteDB/_proc/TimeLog_Checkin(' + ChildID + ')/?app_name=App&fields=*', {ChildID: ChildID}, {
                     update: {
                               method: 'PUT'
                             }
                     });
          }
       }
})
```